# Bootstrap Sidenav Style

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, haml

Im working on a ruby app and i am trying to make a sidenav that looks exactly like the one used on the official bootstrap website as seen here:

[image]

My code for the sidenav:

```
.row-fluid
  .span3
    %ul.nav.nav-list.sidenav
      %li
        %a{:href => "#download-bootstrap"}
          %i.icon-chevron-right
          Download
      %li
        %a{:href => "#file-structure"}
          %i.icon-chevron-right
          File structure
      %li
        %a{:href => "#contents"}
          %i.icon-chevron-right
          What's included
      %li
        %a{:href => "#html-template"}
          %i.icon-chevron-right
          HTML template
      %li
        %a{:href => "#examples"}
          %i.icon-chevron-right
          Examples
      %li
        %a{:href => "#what-next"}
          %i.icon-chevron-right
          What next?
```

And my code for the css (scss):

```
.sidenav {
  width: 207px;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.065);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.065);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.065);
  > {
    li {
      > a {
        display: block;
        width: 190px \9;
        margin: 0 0 -1px;
        padding: 8px 14px;
        border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
      }
      &:first-child > a {
        -webkit-border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
        -moz-border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
        border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
      }
      &:last-child > a {
        -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
        -moz-border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
        border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
      }
    }
    .active > a {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 2;
      padding: 9px 15px;
      border: 0;
      text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset -1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      -moz-box-shadow: inset 1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset -1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      box-shadow: inset 1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset -1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }
  }
  .icon-chevron-right {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-right: -6px;
    opacity: .25;
  }
  > li > a:hover {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
  }
  a:hover .icon-chevron-right {
    opacity: .5;
  }
  .active {
    .icon-chevron-right, a:hover .icon-chevron-right {
      background-image: url(../img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png);
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
}
```

I also have the standard `bootstrap.css` and `bootstrap-responsive.css` included as well. Does anyone know why this is happening. Mine seems very thin. My output looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code seems right. Have you tried inspecting the element? (right click > inspect). It could be that somewhere in your CSS the padding for the 'a' tag is getting reset. When you inspect the element you'll be able to see where the padding is getting changed.

Comment: I figured out that when i use the gem 'less-rails'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails' gems it works but i prefer to use gem 'less-rails-bootstrap' which it doesn't work on. Any idea why?